# Find generic method with actual types from getDeclaredMethods

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have generic classes that look like:

```
interface X<Input, Output>
{
  Output process(Input input);
}

class Y implements X<Integer, Float> 
{   
  Float process(Integer input); 
}
```

I use getDeclaredMethods to find process on Y just with its name (not the arguments, on purpose). When I look at the return Method[], process shows up twice, with Input=Object, Output=Object, and then with the actual instantiation types: Integer and Float.

Please note: I can see 1 function with Object,Object in the Method[] AND 1 function with the actual types I use to instantiate, like Integer,Float. So, the second function, which I'm interested in, is accessible from Method[].

What is the best way to get only the method with the actual types?

Comment: Do you have actual subclasses of `X` with hardcoded values for `Input` and `Output`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Comment: Note also, that I slightly modified the question, from class to interface, which is actually my real case. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Curious why you are looking for this. You *can* call the generic method (with types erased) using reflection.

Comment: Because I'm working on the types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and then with the actual instantiation types.

That's not possible. You should see a single method whose parameter types are `Object`. You can also look at the method's generic parameter and return types, and you will find that they are both type variables (`Input` and `Output` are type variables).

*Subclasses* of this class that inherit from it with *specific* type arguments for the type parameters, will have two methods: a method with the more specific parameter and return types, and a *bridge method*, with the original class's method's parameter and return types, in order to override it. If you are asking how to ignore the bridge method, simply check if it's a bridge method (`.isBridge()`)

Comment: Check it out. Note my change of the original question to interface/class.

Comment: Got it. That was my question. isBridge() is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Generic types are known only at compilation time. `Object` is the actual type of generics at runtime, so you can't get them while running the program.

Comment: Are you saying that Object is the dynamic type of generic parameters?

Comment: Due to Java's type erasure concept, that's the way generics work at runtime.

Comment: @Frank: parameter type is a compile-time (static) thing. "dynamic type of generic parameters" does not make sense.